# Update a published Action on Google

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Recently, I built an Action on Google and followed the official docs. I built it and pushed it for review. The google team deployed it after reviewing it as well. Now I wanted to add some new functionalities to the existing Action. However, I am faced a slight issue in doing so.

I used DialogFlow to create the agent and Firebase functions as my webhook fulfillment. Now the changes made to the agent are in draft of new version and does not affect the live version, but changing the firebase function affects my live action as the firebase function gets deployed on same URL. I also received an e-mail stating that **health of my action is critical** as the webhook was not replying to requests properly (As i was making some changes).

To solve this, I created another firebase function and added my all old and new functionalities to this new function and updated it as the webhook fulfillment of my same DialogFlow agent which is in draft now. After satisfactory testing, I published the same agent again and it got successfully deployed.

My question here is that, **is there any other mechanism to update a published action other than creating new firebase functions ?** As In alexa skill development two instance of a skills get created when a skill goes live : Live and Development. Changes in development mode (both the interaction model and backend code deployment) does not affect the live skill.

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow has a [versioning and environment system](https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/versions-environments) which enables you to setup a "beta" track of your action with its own fulfillment while you prototype.